# How to maintain a variable throughout different activities and not use shared preferences

Tags: java, android

I want to keep track of a variable through different Activities, but I don't want to use [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

I can have a class with a static variable and static methods, but when the application is closed and opened again I lose the data.

```
// Data lost when app is closed.
public class DataHolder
{
    static boolean isDone = false;

    public static boolean isDone()
    {
        return isDone;
    }

    public static void setIsDone(boolean done)
    {
        isDone = done;
    }
}
```

**How can I persist data while my device is on?**

Basically I want my data to stay active until I reboot the device.

---

I don't want to use Shared Preferences because data has to reset the moment I reboot. And I don't think I can catch a reboot to clear data. I guess I could clear the Shared Preferences when `BOOT_COMPLETED`, but maybe someone has a better idea.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the SharedPreferences/BOOT_COMPLETED approach you suggest.  Using a BroadcastReceiver to detect reboots is reliable and a common practice.  And you are right to prefer SharedPreferences for global data, as it avoids all of the pitfalls of storing the data in memory (process kills, etc).  In short, I do not think there is a better approach.

Comment: isin't database meant for that

Comment: @EJK Thanks, you are the only person that understood the problem I presented in my question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know save your data to a persistent storage is good answer for your question. Let's use SharedPreferences and BOOT_COMPLETED as you said.

Comment: So if I am asking for a better idea, how does your post (my idea) answer the question? At least provide why it is better than any other alternative.

Comment: Sorry. As you know, to keep data after shutdown the app you need to save them into a persistent storage. It maybe a file, a Sqlite database, or a SharedPerferences. And I see that using SharedPrefernces is the simplest. And BOOT_COMPLETED is also easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use database to save your data, any inconvenience?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **static** variable.
but it will destroy once your application destroy completely otherwise it will work fine, throughout the application

Answer (score 0):

Android's [`Application`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) Object could replace your `DataHolder` Object.

Class description

> Base class for those who need to maintain global application state. You can provide your own implementation by specifying its name in your AndroidManifest.xml's `<application>` tag, which will cause that class to be instantiated for you when the process for your application/package is created.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem because if I close my app then I lose the data.

Answer (score 0):

There is 3 ways to store data in persistent storage  in android
1.SharedPreference
2.database
3.File